# Rspec test can not locate method in model file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

My rspec test vote__spec.rb is stating that my up_votes method is undefined but it is listed within the votes.rb file listed below. Can anyone guide me on why its stating it is undefined?

**Rspec error**

```
2) Vote validations value validation only allows -1 or 1 as values
 Failure/Error: expect(@votes.up_votes).where(value: [1,-1])
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `up_votes' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/models/vote_spec.rb:5:in `block (4 levels) in <top    (required)>'
```

**Vote Rspec**

```
describe Vote do
 describe "validations" do
  describe "value validation" do
    it "only allows -1 or 1 as values" do
    expect(@post.up_votes).where(value: [1,-1]) 
  end
 end
end
end
```

**Vote.rb file**

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :post

  def up_votes
   votes.where(value: 1).count
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is appearing because the @post variable needs to be initialized. Once I initialized the @post variable as shown below, the error is resolved:

```
before do
  @post = Post.create(title: 'Post title', body: 'Post bodies must be   pretty long.')
  3.times {@post.votes.create(value: 1)}
  2.times {@post.votes.create(value: -1)}
end
```